# Firmware not running - cannot dump error Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wireless, firmware

I have a Dell Vostro 5590 laptop and the wifi worked fine until now. Suddenly Ubuntu can't find any wifi adapters. I'm still pretty new to linux, so I'm not sure what to do. I found that it's a firmware issue, so I tried to downgrade using synoptic, but that didn't work, therefore I upgraded again.

Here is some terminal output:

```
    (base) sarah@sarah-Vostro-5590:~$ lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:c2318000-c231bfff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 15
       serial: f0:d4:e2:f1:80:0d
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.27 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c2204000-c2204fff memory:c2200000-c2203fff

    (base) sarah@sarah-Vostro-5590:~$ dmesg | grep -i firm
[    0.183598] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.926505] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    1.939148] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 48.13675109.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    1.940042] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-19-0-0.sfi
[    2.083344] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    2.187648] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[    2.320323] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PXSX) defines _DOD but not _DOS
[    3.114868] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 48.13675109.0
[    3.115062] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    3.527261] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[    3.527451] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1564676 usecs
```

I'm using the following kernel 5.3.0-40-generic. As I said, I'm a bit of a noob. I would have tried to remove the battery, but I would need to unscrew the entire bottom, so if anyone has a more sophisicated solution, I'd be happy to hear it!

Comment: It has nothing to do woth a battery. Boot with a previous kernel using grub. This is some kernel bug.

Comment: That worked, thanks a million for the fast reply!

Comment: I think package backport-iwlwifi-dkms fixes the issue in 5.3.0-40 but using an older kernel temporarily might be better